# Form Session variables not stored in form in IE 8,10

Tags: php, session, internet-explorer-8, browser

Form values are not stored in IE browser.After the form submits and the captch code entered is worng i want form values to be there but in IE browsers the session values are not stored
..i checkd in other browsers it is working fine there

```
      <?php
   session_start();
   ob_flush();
   include("header.php");

  if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))   
  {

  if ($_POST["vercode"] != $_SESSION["vercode"] OR $_SESSION["vercode"]=='')
  { 
    $msg="Incorrect verification code";

    $ssubject   =   $_POST['Subject'];
    $name       =   $_POST['name'];
    $address    =   $_POST['address'];
    $email      =   $_POST['email'];
    $phone      =   $_POST['phone'];
    $comments   =   $_POST['comments'];

    $_SESSION['Subject']    =   $ssubject;
    $_SESSION['name']       =   $name;
    $_SESSION['address']    =   $address;
    $_SESSION['email']      =   $email;
    $_SESSION['phone']      =   $phone;
    $_SESSION['comments']   =   $comments;

   }
    else
   {


    $email_to="abccc@gmail.com";

   $ssubject    =   $_POST['Subject'];
   $name        =   $_POST['name'];
   $address =   $_POST['address'];
   $email       =   $_POST['email'];
   $phone       =   $_POST['phone'];
   $comments    =   $_POST['comments'];

   $to      =       $email_to;

  $subject="Message from abc Website Inquiry"." ".date("D dS M,Y h:i a");

  $header="from: abc$email";

    $messages= "INQUIRY\r\n\r\nSUBJECT: $ssubject\r\n\r\nNAME: $name \r\n\r\nADDRESS: $address \r\n\r\nEMAIL:$email \r\n\r\nPHONE:$phone \r\n\r\nCOMMENTS: $comments\r\n";

  $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$messages,$header);

  if($sentmail)
  {

    $success="Your Contact Details Has Been Sent To Administrator Address.";
    unset($_SESSION['Subject']);
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['address']);
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['phone']);
    unset($_SESSION['comments']);

 }

 }
   }
   ?>
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateEmail()
    {

       var emailID = document.email_check.email.value;
       atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
       dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
       if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
       {
           alert("Please enter valid email ID")
           document.email_check.email.focus() ;
           return false;
       }
       return( true );
    }


        function validateForm()
        {
            var a = document.forms["form1"]["name"].value;
            var b = document.forms["form1"]["phone"].value;
            var c = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
            var d = document.forms["form1"]["comments"].value;
            var e = document.forms["form1"]["vercode"].value;

           if(a==null || a=="")
            {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

           if(b==null || b=="")
            {
                alert("Phone must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

            if( document.email_check.email.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Email must be filled out!" );
                document.email_check.email.focus() ;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
            // Put extra check for data format
                var ret = validateEmail();
                if( ret == false )
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if(d==null || d=="")
            {
                alert("Comments must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            if(e==null || e=="")
            {
                alert("Code must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

        }
          </script> 

           <div class="baner_outer" style="border-bottom:solid 6px #e1e2e2; margin:0 0 21px 0;padding:0 0 2px 0;">
          <div class=" wrapper">
    <img src="images/sub_baner5.jpg" height="224" width="1003" />
    </div>
  </div>

<div class=" center_outer1">
 <div class="wrapper">
<div class="center_inner">
 <div class="welcome_left">

            <form id="form1"  name="email_check" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="">


            <div class="wel_cont" >

            <h3 style="color:#F00;">
            <?php 
            if($msg){ echo $msg;}

            ?>
            </h3>
            <h3 style="color:#F90;"><?php if($success){echo $success;}?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="namepart">
                 <h5>Subject</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="tex_part">
            <select name="Subject">
                <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
                <option value="Appointment Request" selected="selected">
    Appointment Request</option>
                <option value="Doctors inquiry">a Inquiry</option>
                <option value="Service Inquiry">Service Inquiry</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <br />


          <div class="wel_cont">
            <div class="namepart"><h5>Name</h5></div>
            <div class="tex_part"><input name="name" 
     class="text_box" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>"/></div>
            <br />
           </div>

          <div class="wel_cont">
            <div class="namepart"><h5>Address</h5></div>
            <div class="tex_part"><textarea class="text_boxlarge" name="address">
           <?php echo $_SESSION['address'];?></textarea></div>
            <br />
           </div>

          <div class="wel_cont">
            <div class="namepart"><h5>Phone number</h5></div>
            <div class="tex_part">
            <input name="phone" class="text_box" type="text" 
       validation="required phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone'];?>"/></div>
            <br />
            </div>


          <div class="wel_cont">
      <div class="namepart"><h5>Email</h5></div>
            <div class="tex_part">
            <input name="email" class="text_box" type="text"  
         validation="required email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>"/></div>
            <br />                 
            </div>



          <div class="wel_cont">
            <div class="namepart"><h5>Comments</h5></div>
            <div class="tex_part"><textarea class="text_boxlarge" name="comments"><?php echo $_SESSION['comments'];?></textarea></div>
          </div>

          <div class="wel_cont">
        <div class="namepart"><h5>Enter Code</h5></div>
        <div class="tex_part">
            <img src="captcha.php">
            <input type="text" name="vercode" 
       class="text_box"     style="width:120px;margin-top:16px;" /> 
        </div>
        </div>


    <div class="submit1">
    <div class="send_buttons">
     <input name="Submit"  type="image" src="images/submit_burron1.jpg" 
   height="20" width="54" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div class="send_buttons">
        <input name="cancel" type="image" src="images/reset_button.jpg" 
  height="20" width="54" usemap="#Map2Map" />
    </div>


    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you remember to start your session `session_start();`

Comment: @J2D8T yes i have started session on top before anything..

Comment: sessions are not browser specific. they are server related, why would you get a browser related issue with sessions

Comment: @susheel I was just asking him if he remembered because it wasn't in the code before the first edit. That is why it is a comment and I didn't add it as an answer, maybe you should go read the about page's section about commenting.

Comment: i was not replying to you by the way..@J2D8T i was asking the user

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be that in IE you do not accept the session cookie. For sessions to work you somehow need to pass the Session ID from one page to another. This can be done using cookies or appending the Session ID to the URL. Default setting is to use cookies.

See [Passing the Session ID](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) section in the PHP manual.

Comment: can u give more details please

Comment: But we are not passing values to any other page ..form action is same page

Comment: When the form is submitted a new page is loaded. If this new page is the same as the current page this does not make a difference. For details on the Session ID have a look at the [PHP manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)